# How to prevent a UIView.animate from being called

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uiviewanimation

I'd like to reproduce the behavior of WhatsApp buttons on the ongoing call view: they disappear a few seconds after appearing, and every time the user taps the screen, they appear again.

Let's say I have those two buttons,

```
@IBOutlet weak var callButton: UIButton!
@IBOutlet weak var muteButton: UIButton!
```

This is the snippet called when `viewDidAppear` is entered as well as when the user taps the screen:

```
self.callButton.alpha = 1.0
self.muteButton.alpha = 1.0
delay(4.0) {
    UIView.animate(withDuration: 1.0, animations: {
        self.callButton.alpha = 0.0
        self.muteButton.alpha = 0.0
    }, completion: { _ in })
}

func delay(_ seconds: Double, completion: @escaping () -> ()) {
    let popTime = DispatchTime.now() + Double(Int64(Double(NSEC_PER_SEC) * seconds)) / Double(NSEC_PER_SEC)
    DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: popTime) {
        completion()
    }
}
```

With this code, if the user taps the screen like 3 seconds after the previous call, the buttons will still disappear 1 second later. So I would like to know how I can block the previous `UIView.animate` if the view is tapped again meanwhile.

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, why are you creating a delay method when one has been provided to you in `UIView.animate` by Apple?

Now, to achieve what you want, just use a flag to check if the method has been called once already and prevent the method call.

```
var animating = false

func yourAnimateMethod() {
    if !animating {
        animating = true
        UIView.animate(withDuration: 1, delay: 4, options: .curveLinear, animations: {
            self.callButton.alpha = 0.0
            self.muteButton.alpha = 0.0
        }) { (completed) in
            if completed {
                animating = false
            }
        }
    }
}
```